# Commutative composition of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ and $g$ be two polynomials. What can we conclude if
$$f(g(x))=g(f(x)).$$
I can only check some trivial cases like $f(x)=x^n$ and $g(x)=x^m$.

Comment: There are non-trivial examples...The Chebyshev polynomials all commute, for instance.  see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2411292/commutative-property-of-chebyshev-polynomial)

Comment: According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/11442/949989) there is a classic result by Ritt which classifies all polynomials that commute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When functions commute under composition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11431/when-functions-commute-under-composition)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I may read the materials first.